# Comparing local and server files from emacs

Tags: emacs, terminal, editor

I am a new user to emacs. I need to compare two files, one local file and another in a server.

I fireup emacs opening my local file. Now I split emacs into two using C-x 3. Now I opened up a shell in my second frame on the right. I opened a shell using M-x shell. Now ssh-ed into my server. I navigated to a deep location and I need to open a file from this location on my right buffer. I tried C-x C-f but its showing my location directory?

Is there a solution for this?

Edit:
I think I stressed my problem wrongly. I just want to see both files open in emacs and read them together. Not really a diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Tramp and ediff. Something like

```
M-x ediff-files RET
/local/path/to/file RET
/ssh:user@host:/remote/path/to/file RET
```

`user` and `host` are the arguments you need for ssh.

Comment: I think I stressed my problem incorrectly. I just need to open these two files at the same time

Comment: I still believe, that the `ediff` comparison is the best for you. However, if you want to open both files in different buffers, apply `C-x C-f /local/path/to/file RET C-x-C-f /ssh:user@host:/remote/path/to/file RET`